# understanding of sql editionId property

Tags: sql, asp.net, connection

I'm trying to connect sql DB to my asp.net project,but getting an error :The server was not found or was not accessible.
After checking the connectionstring in my DAL class (c#) and all my values, i found that in this line

```
 string sqlServer = Environment.MachineName + "\\" + sqlServerName;
```

sqlServer is SQLEXPRESS.

but when i checked my sql with:

```
select serverproperty('Edition')
```

the result was : Enterprise Edition (64-bit) and not SQLEXPRESS.
Can this difference be the reason for my error ? if its a problem what is the solution ?

Comment: You can check this: SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('ServerName'). This returns your SqlServer name that you can use in your connection string.

Comment: the serverName passes with no problems the difference is with the edition of sql.